# Are shiny Pokémon more powerful than regular Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've read that shiny Pokémon now exist in Pokémon Go.

See for example [this article](http://bgr.com/2017/03/22/pokemon-go-how-to-catch-shiny-pokemon/).

If I have a regular Pokémon and a shiny Pokémon,
both with the same IVs and attacks, are they identical in terms of battling strength?

Comment: It's entirely sarcastic, but I have seen #ShiniesDoMoreDamage trending in competitive Pokemon Go groups.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both Pokemon will be identical in terms of battling strength.

As in the Pokemon games, the only difference between the a shiny Pokemon and a normal one is the fact that the color of the shiny one is different (adding a glow effect too). But the logic of the stats of the Pokemon remains the same. So a shiny Magikarp wouldn't be stronger than a normal one.

It has been mentioned in [this article](http://heavy.com/games/2017/03/pokemon-go-what-are-shiny-creatures-species-what-is-special-about-history-are-more-powerful-magikarp-gyarados/) that:

> The shiny Pokemon are not actually inherently more powerful than their less shiny counterparts. In fact, the early evidence suggests that there’s really no link between a Pokemon’s shininess and its individual values.

Comment: "As in the Pokemon games" back in gen 2 shinyness was based on IVs, so it did have a relation to the pokemon's stats (afaict the IV's needed for shinyness were above-average but not the best). In gen 3 and later this was dropped.